# Error after updating scikit-learn to version 0.20.1 : cannot import name 'Empty' from 'queue'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I upgraded scikit-learn to version 0.20.1 using anaconda3 after getting an error message concerning balanced_accuracy_score from metrics in scikit-learn. This is apparently not available in version 0.19.

After this upgrade i get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn import metrics
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 6
4, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 13, i
n <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py",
line 14, in <module>
    from . import _joblib
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_joblib.py", l
ine 22, in <module>
    from ..externals import joblib
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\__i
nit__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from .parallel import Parallel
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\par
allel.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_pa
rallel_backends.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .executor import get_memmapping_executor
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\exe
cutor.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .externals.loky.reusable_executor import get_reusable_executor
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\ext
ernals\loky\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .reusable_executor import get_reusable_executor
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\ext
ernals\loky\reusable_executor.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .process_executor import ProcessPoolExecutor, EXTRA_QUEUED_CALLS
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\ext
ernals\loky\process_executor.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .backend.queues import Queue, SimpleQueue, Full
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\ext
ernals\loky\backend\queues.py", line 21, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.queues import Full
  File "C:\Users\Pieter\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 20, in <m
odule>
    from queue import Empty, Full
ImportError: cannot import name 'Empty' from 'queue' (C:\Users\Pieter\Python pro
gs\queue.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running this program from `"C:\Users\Pieter\Python progs"`?

Looks like you have a file named `queue.py` in `"C:\Users\Pieter\Python pro
gs\"` which is shadowing the actual module `queue` in `multiprocessing` lib. And hence the error.

There are two possible reasons for this:

1. Maybe this line:

   ```
   from queue import Empty, Full
   ```

   has been added in new version, so earlier it did not error even when your custom made `queue.py` was present.
2. Maybe you have created your `queue.py` recently after updating the scikit-learn and the above line was always present. In this case, error should occur on both versions.

Rename your program from `queue.py` and auto-compiled `queue.pyc` 
to something else and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! This worked after deleting an additional queue.pyc file. I wondered why this wasn't an issue with the earlier version of scikit-learn, perhaps it has no file named queue.py.

Comment: @PolProt See my second point and try to remember about when you created your `queue.py` file. Is it after the update or before? If before, can you again try downgrading to 0.19 (with the queue.py present in your folder) and repeat the process?

Comment: Vivek, it was before the update, I indeed tried rolling back to 0.19 and there was no issue there.

Comment: @PolProt Oh ok then. Just rename that.